# graphViz: How to use fixed positions for nodes from "neato" layout but have pretty curved edges from "dot" layout?

Tags: graph, graphviz, diagrammer, r-graphviz

I have this dot code which I use in R's `diagrammeR`-package:

```
grViz("digraph {

  graph [layout = neato,
  overlap = false,
  outputorder = edgesfirst]
       
  node [shape = rectangle]
      
# Error Certainty
crt1e[pos = '11.1,  15!',  label = '0.11', width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt2e[pos = '12.3,  15!',  label = '0.11', width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt3e[pos = '13.5,  15!',  label = '0.11', width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt4e[pos = '14.7,  15!',  label = '0.11', width = 0.9, shape = none]

# Certainty
crt1 [pos = '11.1,  14!',  label = 'crt1', width = 0.9]
crt2 [pos = '12.3,  14!',  label = 'crt2', width = 0.9]
crt3 [pos = '13.5,  14!',  label = 'crt3', width = 0.9]
crt4 [pos = '14.7,  14!',  label = 'crt4', width = 0.9]

# Latent Certainty
crt  [pos = '12.9,  12!',  label = 'crt',  width = 1.3, shape = circle]

# Path Certainty
crt->crt1 [label = '0.6']
crt->crt2 [label = '0.6']
crt->crt3 [label = '0.6']
crt->crt4 [label = '0.6']

# Covariance
crt3:n->crt4:n[label = '0.7', dir = both, constraint = false]

# Error Path
crt1e->crt1
crt2e->crt2
crt3e->crt3
crt4e->crt4
}")
```

[image: SEM using neato layout]

This looks exactly as I want it to, except for the edge between crt3 and crt4. I want this edge to be curved upwards. I also need to control position of each node manually. How can I achieve both at the same time?

I have tried to use the "dot" layout. This creates a nicely curved edge for crt3->crt4 but it does not support fixed positions.

[image: SEM using dot layout]

Adding a dummy node between crt3 and crt4 and using splines = true messed up the distances between all nodes in my diagram.

**EDIT**

I tried the suggested solution in a bigger context. Here, the edges are drawn over each other instead of spreading out.

```
grViz("digraph SEM{

graph [layout = neato,
outputorder = edgesfirst,
# overlap = false,
splines = true]
     
node [shape = rectangle, width = 0.7, height = 0.3]

# Nodes
eu   [pos = '-1,  5!',  width = 1.3, shape = circle]
nrm  [pos = '-1,  0!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]
inf  [pos = '-3, 6.5!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]
cns  [pos = '-3, 3.5!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]

clr  [pos = '6, 5!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]
crt  [pos = '6, 2.5!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]
cor  [pos = '6, 0!', width = 1.3, shape = circle]

inf1 [pos = '-5, 7.5!']
inf2 [pos = '-5, 7!']
inf3 [pos = '-5, 6.5!']
inf4 [pos = '-5, 6!']
inf5 [pos = '-5, 5.5!']

cns1 [pos = '-5, 4.25!']
cns2 [pos = '-5, 3.75!']
cns3 [pos = '-5, 3.25!']
cns4 [pos = '-5, 2.75!']

nrm1 [pos = '-5, 1.5!']
nrm2 [pos = '-5, 1!']
nrm3 [pos = '-5, 0.5!']
nrm4 [pos = '-5, 0!']
nrm5 [pos = '-5, -0.5!']
nrm6 [pos = '-5, -1!']
nrm7 [pos = '-5, -1.5!']

clr1 [pos = '10, 5.75!']
clr2 [pos = '10, 5.25!']
clr3 [pos = '10, 4.75!']
clr4 [pos = '10, 4.25!']

crt1 [pos = '10, 3.25!']
crt2 [pos = '10, 2.75!']
crt3 [pos = '10, 2.25!']
crt4 [pos = '10, 1.75!']

cor1 [pos = '10, 0.5!']
cor2 [pos = '10, 0!']
cor3 [pos = '10, -0.5!']

inf1e[pos = '-6, 7.5!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
inf2e[pos = '-6, 7!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
inf3e[pos = '-6, 6.5!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
inf4e[pos = '-6, 6!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
inf5e[pos = '-6, 5.5!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]

cns1e[pos = '-6, 4.25!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
cns2e[pos = '-6, 3.75!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
cns3e[pos = '-6, 3.25!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
cns4e[pos = '-6, 2.75!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]

nrm1e[pos = '-6, 1.5!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
nrm2e[pos = '-6, 1!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
nrm3e[pos = '-6, 0.5!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
nrm4e[pos = '-6, 0!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
nrm5e[pos = '-6, -0.5!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]
nrm6e[pos = '-6, -1!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
nrm7e[pos = '-6, -1.5!', shape = none, label = '1.12', width = 0.05]

clr1e[pos = '11, 5.75!', shape = none, label = '3.12', width = 0.05]
clr2e[pos = '11, 5.25!', shape = none, label = '3.12', width = 0.05]
clr3e[pos = '11, 4.75!', shape = none, label = '3.12', width = 0.05]
clr4e[pos = '11, 4.25!', shape = none, label = '3.12', width = 0.05]

crt1e[pos = '11, 3.25!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
crt2e[pos = '11, 2.75!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
crt3e[pos = '11, 2.25!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
crt4e[pos = '11, 1.75!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]

cor1e[pos = '11, 0.5!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
cor2e[pos = '11, 0!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]
cor3e[pos = '11, -0.5!', shape = none, label = '2.12', width = 0.05]

# Edges
eu->inf [taillabel = '0.27', labeldistance = 5, labelangle = -15]
eu->cns [taillabel = '0.37', labeldistance = 3.5, labelangle = -25]

inf->inf1 [label = '0.67']
inf->inf2 [label = '0.56']
inf->inf3 [label = '0.45']
inf->inf4 [label = '0.34']
inf->inf5 [label = '0.23']

cns->cns1 [label = '0.34']
cns->cns2 [label = '0.45']
cns->cns3 [label = '0.56']
cns->cns4 [label = '0.67']

nrm->nrm1 [label = '0.56']
nrm->nrm2 [label = '0.45']
nrm->nrm3 [label = '0.34']
nrm->nrm4 [label = '0.45']
nrm->nrm5 [label = '0.56']
nrm->nrm6 [label = '0.78']
nrm->nrm7 [label = '0.67']

crt->crt1 [label = '0.89']
crt->crt2 [label = '0.90']
crt->crt3 [label = '0.89']
crt->crt4 [label = '0.78']

clr->clr1 [label = '0.67']
clr->clr2 [label = '0.56']
clr->clr3 [label = '0.45']
clr->clr4 [label = '0.34']

cor->cor1 [label = '0.23']
cor->cor2 [label = '0.34']
cor->cor3 [label = '0.56']

eu->nrm [dir = both, label = '.45 ']
eu->clr [dir = both, label = '-.45']
eu->crt [dir = both, taillabel = '-.46', labeldistance = 12, labelangle = 5]
eu->cor [dir = both, taillabel = '-.34', labeldistance = 12, labelangle = 5]
nrm->crt [dir = both, taillabel = '-.23', labeldistance = 12, labelangle = 5]
nrm->clr [dir = both, taillabel = '-.12', labeldistance = 12, labelangle = 6]
nrm->cor [dir = both, label = '-.45']
crt->clr [dir = both, taillabel = '.57', labeldistance = 5, labelangle = -20]
cor->crt [dir = both, taillabel = '.23', labeldistance = 5, labelangle = -20]
clr->cor [dir = both, taillabel = '.36', labeldistance = 9, labelangle = -5]

inf1e->inf1
inf2e->inf2
inf3e->inf3
inf4e->inf4
inf5e->inf5

cns1e->cns1
cns2e->cns2
cns3e->cns3
cns4e->cns4

nrm1e->nrm1
nrm2e->nrm2
nrm3e->nrm3
nrm4e->nrm4
nrm5e->nrm5
nrm6e->nrm6
nrm7e->nrm7

crt1e->crt1
crt2e->crt2
crt3e->crt3
crt4e->crt4

clr1e->clr1
clr2e->clr2
clr3e->clr3
clr4e->clr4

cor1e->cor1
cor2e->cor2
cor3e->cor3

crt3:e->crt4:e [dir = both, label = '.46']
crt3:e->crt4:e [dir = both, label = '.46']
crt3:e->crt4:e [dir = both, label = '.46']
crt3:e->crt4:e [dir = both, label = '.46']
crt3:e->crt4:e [dir = both, label = '.46']

}")
```

[image: new plot]

Comment: is your reference to **splines=true** for **dot** or **neato**?

Comment: this happens with neato

Answer (score 1):

If you add **splines=true** to your input you will get a small curve to the edge:
[image]

But if you add 3 (or so) invisible mult-edges like so:

```
digraph {

  graph [layout = neato,
  overlap = false,
  outputorder = edgesfirst
  splines=true ///curved  // better than true??
  ]
       
  node [shape = rectangle]
      
# Error Certainty
crt1e[pos = "11.1,  15!",  label = "0.11", width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt2e[pos = "12.3,  15!",  label = "0.11", width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt3e[pos = "13.5,  15!",  label = "0.11", width = 0.9, shape = none]
crt4e[pos = "14.7,  15!",  label = "0.11", width = 0.9, shape = none]

# Certainty
crt1 [pos = "11.1,  14!",  label = "crt1", width = 0.9]
crt2 [pos = "12.3,  14!",  label = "crt2", width = 0.9]
crt3 [pos = "13.5,  14!",  label = "crt3", width = 0.9]
crt4 [pos = "14.7,  14!",  label = "crt4", width = 0.9]

# Latent Certainty
crt  [pos = "12.9,  12!",  label = "crt",  width = 1.3, shape = circle]

# Path Certainty
crt->crt1 [label = "0.6"]
crt->crt2 [label = "0.6"]
crt->crt3 [label = "0.6"]
crt->crt4 [label = "0.6"]

# Covariance
crt3:n->crt4:n[label = "", style=invis constraint = false]
crt3:n->crt4:n[label = "", style=invis constraint = false]
crt3:n->crt4:n[label = "", style=invis constraint = false]
crt3:n->crt4:n[label = "0.7", dir = both, constraint = false]

# Error Path
crt1e->crt1
crt2e->crt2
crt3e->crt3
crt4e->crt4
}
```

You will get a more pronounced curve:
[image]

Comment: I added 5 invisible edges and that made it look okay, thank you. I still wonder why there is no layout option to combine fixed node positions with nicely curved edges. It is a standard requirement for SEM path diagrams.

Comment: I changed the position of my nodes, basically rotating the whole diagram 90 degrees to the right. the trick is not working anymore. the dummy edges are all drawn on the same spot. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: please share your new code

Comment: have added the new code as an edit

Comment: Assuming you are talking about `crt3:e->crt4:e`, I do see each of the multi-edges.  I also tried an old version of Graphviz and still see the multi-edges.  Maybe Diagrammer has a bug.  Can you produce the output in the **dot** format (instead of **png** or **svg**)?

Comment: I get an error that the graph object is not valid when trying to export to dot format (or any format, actually). I will try my dot code outside of DiagrammeR. If it is working on your machine, maybe I will be able to make it too. Thanks for looking into it!

Comment: I get the same plot as I posted in the edit when using graphViz directly. `crt3:e->crt4:e` are still overlapping...this is the relevant dot output: `crt3:e -> crt4:e [dir=both,
  label=.46,
  lp="1206.5,271.32",
  pos="s,1197.5,281.5 e,1197.5,245.5 1197.5,270.11 1197.5,265.82 1197.5,260.96 1197.5,256.69"];
 crt3:e -> crt4:e [dir=both,
  label=.46,
  lp="1188.5,271.32",
  pos="s,1197.5,281.5 e,1197.5,245.5 1197.5,270.11 1197.5,265.82 1197.5,260.96 1197.5,256.69"];`

Comment: Let's move this to the Graphviz Forum (https://forum.graphviz.org/)